# How to load static javascript resource in HTML Component

Tags: javascript, html

I've uploaded a jQuery library document into our SF Shared Documents and want to be able to reference that document in a sidebar HTML component. I've tried many variations of the below with no luck:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=015f0000000AdXO"></script>
```

Can someone give me an idea of how the path should be specified?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it is the main jQuery JavaScript, an alternate approach is to just reference it from a CDN location like this `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>`.

Comment: Yeah @Keith, I was trying to avoid an external call for each page that loads.

Comment: Well its the client (the browser) making the request so its a remote call whether to the CDN location or to a Salesforce location... And as long as all your pages reference the same CDN location your browser will cache.

Comment: @KeithC. Turns out what I had was correct. I just had a bad end tag for my script. It was like: '</script text=>'. Once I removed the text attribute I was good to go. Not sure how that got in there. Thanks for the suggestions anyway.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not using static resources to reference your file?

Comment: @greenstork I would guess that one reason is that it would then be necessary to hard-code the static resource timestamp given Visualforce can't be used.

Comment: static resources can be used/referenced without the timestamp @Keith C, it's optional

Comment: @greenstork Thanks - what version do you get in that case?

Comment: I assume the most recent

Comment: @greenstork From http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Delivering_Static_Resources_with_Visualforce looks like up to 24 hours later you might and then only after user's clear their browser's cache.

Answer (score -1):

The best practice is to upload JavaScript libraries as **Static Resources** (Develop -> Static Resources).  Then, use an `<apex:includeScript>` for example:

```
 <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.yourJavaScriptLibrary}"/>
```

Also, you can upload zip files as Static Resources:

```
 <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.SiteFiles,'SiteFiles/JavaScript/Version1.js'}"/>
```

Note: make sure the Static Resource's `Cache Control` is set to `Public`

[image: Image of a Static Resource. Make sure to set Cache Control to Public!]

Comment: The question related to a sidebar component where no "{!}" processing is available. What do you propose for that situation?

Comment: if your problem was solved as your comments suggest, mark it as solved.  ;)  or maybe write it up as a solution . . .

Comment: The wink on the above comment is inappropriate. Clearly this answer is insufficient, considering the original question. At the time of writing this comment, I see no answer submitted for this question that can be considered as having solved the question.

Comment: @amatorVitae, I don't see how to mark a comment as solved. I didn't really want my comment to be an answer, as I didn't feel that it was really a solution to the question, only a revelation of my blunder. Should I delete the post? Or should I mark it as the answer?

Comment: you write up a solution.  it's easy.  the idea is if someone has a similar issue a year from now, they will be able to easily see how to solve their issue.  I ask you to write up a solution for the common good